# Refutations on Kant's approach to Judaism and mitzvos

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, rav-joseph-ber-soloveitchik

I was reading ["The Halakhist as Creator: Rabbi Joseph B. Soloveitchik’s Halakhic Man"](https://torahinmotion.org/sites/default/files/programs/e-tim_the_narrative_of_sefer_tehillim__16.pdf) by Rabbi Reuven Ziegler. It could be considered a thorough summary of the famous sefer "The Halakhic Man" from Rav Soloveitchik zt"l. In it, the author explains different approaches to different (European) philosophical approaches to religion. For example, he quotes [Immanuel Kant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanuel_Kant), a German philosopher and one of the most controversial figures in Western philosophy.

For example, Kant says that Judaism is considered [heteronomous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteronomy), e.g. being influenced/ forced by the force outside an individual. To this, Rav Soloveitchik zt"l responded in two ways, says the author (p. 298)

> First, he shows that there is broad autonomy within Judaism (at least for the master of halakhic study). Halakha is the product of divine revelation; but once halakha was given at Sinai, human reason is its final arbiter both on the level of study (lomdus) and application (pesak). Second, he shows that heteronomy is also important and has its place. In fact, more than the Rav addresses the technical philosophical issue of autonomy, he fosters an ethic of autonomy, a positive evaluation of halakhic man’s sense of freedom, individuality, and self-worth.

Are there other sources that explicitly deal with the refutement of the philosophical ideas of Immanuel Kant? Rav Soloveitchik zt"l is one of them, but I was wondering if there are other works (preferably in English) that give an detailled reaction to these ideas.

Comment: I mean there are a lot of “non Greek philosophies”, which have different relationships to Judaism. I mean Ben Shapiro is an Orthodox Jew and is great friends with Jordan Peterson who is a jungian philosopher. Abraham Isaac Kook ZT’’L  (founding father of religious Zionism) I believe said that atheists believe in god, they just have a different perception of him. That is very similar to how Jordan B. Peterson describes god as a highest archetype in Jungian terms

Comment: I would say so, I mean if god exists in all parts of the universe certainly there is some level of reflection of him (albeit in a distorted way, different to the clear vision of revelation at Mount Sinai) in secular philosophy @shmuel

Comment: Rav Shimshon Raphael Hirsch mentions him in passing - https://www.sefaria.org/Nineteen_Letters.1.8?ven=Bernard_Drachman_translation,_1899&lang=bi&with=About&lang2=en

Comment: https://thelehrhaus.com/scholarship/malbims-paean-to-ben-azzais-kantian-ethics/#_edn6

Comment: If someones downvotes, it would be greatly appreciated if they told me why :)